# Cheaper/faster method to estimate uncertainties than bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error, uncertainty, genetic-algorithms

I'm using a genetic algorithm (GA) to estimate the minimum value of a likelihood function $L[x]$ which is too complicated to evaluate mathematically. This likelihood function quantifies the goodness of fit between a model (which depends on the $x$ parameter) and a set of $M$ observations $O=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_M\}$.

After enough iterations (when the optimal value found by the GA hasn't changed for a while) I stop the GA and assume the value $x_0$ for the model parameter $x$ it settled on, is one that satisfies:

$$L[x_0] \sim min(L[x])$$

which identifies the "best" model/observation fit.

Now, I want to assign an uncertainty to this $x_0$ value for which I apply a bootstrap process with replacement. This means I run the GA again a number $N$ of times (each time using a random sample of $M$ observations taken from $O$) which results in $N$ values for the $x$ parameter: $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$.

Finally I assign the standard deviation of the $N$ values returned by the GA as the uncertainty (error) of $x_0$:

$$e_{x_0} = std(x_1, x_2, ..., x_N)$$

This process works fine, but since I am forced to run the GA a large $N$ number of times, this can quickly become unmanageable in computational time.

The question is: is there a faster/computationally cheaper way of assigning uncertainty to a parameter value estimated through a genetic algorithm?

Comment: jackknife?  Using the parameter estimate as the starting value?

Comment: Is the parameter continuous? Bounded/unbounded?

Comment: Have you looked at the caret package? Is fast and cheap more important than accuracy of your estimate?

Comment: @Glen_b the parameter is not continuous (varies in steps of my choosing, smaller if I want more precision) and it is bounded (also set by me)

Comment: @David not really a connoisseur of CRAN's enormous set of packages, I'm more of a `python` guy. Would you like to expand in the form of an answer? Perhaps it's what I need. Add: I'd say they are both equally important, can't really afford to lose that much accuracy.

Comment: @Gabriel You seem to be taking "parameter" in a sense other than the [statistical meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_parameter) of the word. I intend only the statistical meaning.

Comment: Parameters are not things you control, or observe.

Comment: @Glen_b I mean _parameter_ as _variable_, in the sense that it is a number that can take several values and I want to obtain the "optimal" value and its associated uncertainty. Is it more clear now? What part of the question is not clear to you?

Comment: See my first comment. Since *I* was asking a question about the parameter, it's *my* intended meaning there that is presently under discussion. Your answer, using a different meaning, doesn't respond to it, so I pointed out why not. I'm looking for an answer to that question, which is relevant if one is attempting to give a statistical answer.

Comment: I'm not a statistician and I sincerely have no idea what _statistical parameter_ means in this context. Would you be willing to explain it to me? We can move this to chat.